# Can h2o allow to allocate more memory to standalone cluster?

Tags: python-3.x, memory, h2o

I want to increase the h2o cluster memory up to 64gb. Can I do that yes or no? If no then it should be equal or less to my system memory? or if yes then how much I can allocate?

```
import h2o
h2o.init(nthreads=-1,max_mem_size='16g')
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes you can, the max_mem_size prevents H2o from using more memrory than that amount of memory, and min_men_size initializes the size

Comment: @Mnfr my system have 20 gb ram  can i allocate    64 gb ?

Answer (score 2):

The max_mem_size parameter goes straight to the Xmx parameter for the Java heap allocated to the h2o backend process.

Because java is a garbage collected language, you never want to make the java heap size larger than about 90% of physical memory or you run the risk of uncontrollable swapping.

Comment: Hi @TomKraljevic my system has 20 GB ram. Can I allocate 64gb to that because two times it shut down and show me your pc ran out of memory

Comment: @SanjayKumar When Tom says 90%... if you have 20GB, you could try `max_mem_size=18g`, but any higher is likely to be unstable. 64gb is a definite no. :-)
The best way to get 64GB would be to find another 3 machines of the same size, and have them each start a node with 16GB, and form a cluster.

Comment: Thanks, TomKraljevic and @DarrenCook for clear that confusion